# Ubuntu - PostegreSQL displays errors in foreign language even after changing all locales to en_US and reinstalling it

Tags: linux, ubuntu, locale, postgresql, language

I inherited a Ubuntu desktop from another employee and installed PostgreSQL with the help of [the official guide](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/).

```
abc@lenovo:~$ sudo apt install postgresql-15
```

I had not known that I had to setup an account first so when I tried to create a database I got an error. I now know how to create a user and that is not the question.

```
abc@lenovo:~$ createdb
createdb: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: 치명적오류:  "abc" 롤(role) 없음
```

Notice how a small portion of the error is in a foreign language. To ensure everything is in English going forward, I edited all locales listed in `/etc/default/locale` to be `en_US.UTF-8`.

```
abc@lenovo:~$ sudo vim /etc/default/locale
abc@lenovo:~$ cat /etc/default/locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en
```

Then I rebooted my system. However the message that `PostgreSQL` generates still contained foreign language. Assuming that it simply did not apply the locale changes, I uninstalled then reinstalled the package.

```
abc@lenovo:~$ sudo apt remove postgresql-15
abc@lenovo:~$ sudo apt install postgresql-15
```

Then I checked `PostgreSQL`'s own settings.

```
abc@lenovo:~$ grep lc_ /etc/postgresql/15/main/postgresql.conf
lc_messages = 'en_US.UTF-8'         # locale for system error message
lc_monetary = 'en_US.UTF-8'         # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'en_US.UTF-8'          # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'en_US.UTF-8'             # locale for time formatting
```

It correctly inherited the new default locale settings from the system. However the error message had not changed a bit.

```
abc@lenovo:~$ createdb
createdb: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: 치명적오류:  "abc" 롤(role) 없음
```

Did I miss a locale setting? Do I need to manually wipe some cache stored deep inside? Why is the error message nevertheless mixed?

Comment: Does the computer's `psql` command have its own set of config files, such as `~/.psqlrc`, where the language/locale is being set?  The 'FILES' section of `man psql` may give the exact path names to the server-wide and per-user files.

Comment: Hangeul/Korean? Wow. An `apt remove` doesn't necessarily get rid of config. Note down the numerical UID of the postgres user. Do an `apt purge`. Do a `sudo find / -uid <ID>`, check that the files indeed belong(ed) to postgres and then repeat the find w/ a `-delete` tacked on ... Try again.